# Regular expression match in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract a certain part of the text from a file. 
I'm having trouble making the regular expression match the least number of characters as possible.

Here is an example text file.

```
UNIQUE
sdkjbskdfb....
UNIQUE
lnasdljnkjn......
UNIQUE
*Text from here is needed*
UNIQUE2
*Text from here is needed*
UNIQUE
```

My best effort was this. `"UNIQUE(.\*?)UNIQUE2(.\*?)UNIQUE"`

Unfortunately this matches the whole thing because it uses the first `UNIQUE` value instead of the third one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a negative lookahead:

```
UNIQUE((?:(?!UNIQUE).)*?)UNIQUE2(.*?)UNIQUE
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GWLPMoaEUxGSzi_V)

This says, find `UNIQUE` followed by some string that doesn't contain `UNIQUE` again before you hit `UNIQUE2`, etc.

Let me know if you need clarification.